# append external data to input tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

1:- I am trying to create tag input, as if we type anything inside `tags-container` input new tags will be pushed to tags,
2:- if we click  the tags(from `unique-product-tag` list)
 Those should be added to the same tags-container, so we can type a new tag, or add from the list,

```
<div class="tag-container">
  <input>
</div>

<span class="unique-product-tag">
  <button class="get-tag-data">Tag1</button>
  <button class="get-tag-data">Tag2</button>
  <button class="get-tag-data">Tag3</button>
  <button class="get-tag-data">Tag3</button>
  <button class="get-tag-data">Tag4</button>
  <button class="get-tag-data">Tag5</button>
  <button class="get-tag-data">Tag6</button>
  <button class="get-tag-data">Tag7</button>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.tag-container{
  border:1px solid rgb(85, 82, 82);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.unique-product-tag {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 22px;
}
.tag, .unique-product-tag button{
  background: rgb(240, 238, 238);
  border:1px solid  rgb(240, 238, 238);;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display:flex;
}
.tag-container input{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
}
```

Javascript

```
const tagContainer = document.querySelector('.tag-container');
  const input = document.querySelector('.tag-container input');

  let tags = [];

  function createTag(label){
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'tag');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = label;
    const closeBtn = document.createElement('i');
    closeBtn.setAttribute('class', 'close-tag');
    closeBtn.setAttribute('data-item', label);
    closeBtn.innerHTML = '&times;';

    div.appendChild(span);
    div.appendChild(closeBtn);
    return div;
  }

function reset(){
  document.querySelectorAll('.tag').forEach(function(tag){
    tag.parentElement.removeChild(tag);
  })
}
function addTags(){
  reset();
  tags.slice().reverse().forEach(function(tag){
    const input = createTag(tag);
    tagContainer.prepend(input);
  })
}

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  if(e.key === 'Enter'){
    tags.push(input.value);
    addTags();
    input.value='';
  }
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName == 'I'){
    const value = e.target.getAttribute('data-item');
    console.log(value, 'dhbdbd');
    const index = tags.indexOf(value);
    tags = [...tags.slice(0, index), ...tags.slice(index + 1)];
    addTags();

  }
})
```

Uptill now, my code works as expected, but I am in searching to correct the below code

```
    let tagel = document.querySelectorAll('.get-tag-data');
            for(let i = 0; i < tagel.length; i++){
                tagel[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
                    let data = event.target.innerHTML;
                    tags.push(data);
                    console.log(data);
                });         
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand clearly where you want to add the tags but:

- If to the input then you can use `input.value = tags;`
- If to the `div.tag-container` then you can use `tagContainer.innerHTML += data;` to append the data (or without the `+` to replace the content). It can be any HTML you want your data to be wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript,

```
const tagContainer = document.querySelector('.tag-container');
const input = document.querySelector('.tag-container input');

let tags = [];

function createTag(label){
  // const tagList = document.querySelectorAll('.get-tag-data')
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('class', 'tag');
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = label;
  const closeBtn = document.createElement('i');
  closeBtn.setAttribute('class', 'close-tag');
  closeBtn.setAttribute('data-item', label);
  closeBtn.innerHTML = '&times;';

  div.appendChild(span);
  div.appendChild(closeBtn);
  return div;
}

function reset(){
  document.querySelectorAll('.tag').forEach(function(tag){
    tag.parentElement.removeChild(tag);
  });
}

function addTags(){
  reset();
  tags.slice().reverse().forEach(function(tag){
    const input = createTag(tag);
    tagContainer.prepend(input);
  })
}

document.querySelectorAll('.get-tag-data').forEach(function(tag){
  tag.addEventListener('click', function(eve){
    let val = eve.target.innerHTML;
    console.log(val);
    tags.push(val);
    addTags();
    // val = '';
    return tag;
  });
})

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  if(e.key === 'Enter'){
    tags.push(input.value);
    addTags();
    input.value='';
  }
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName == 'I'){
    const value = e.target.getAttribute('data-item');
    const index = tags.indexOf(value);
    tags = [...tags.slice(0, index), ...tags.slice(index + 1)];
    addTags();
  }
})
```